# error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, aspect, pointcut

the exception trace is：

```
 Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut peformance
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:839)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:538)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:125)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:109)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:261)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: error at ::0 can't find referenced pointcut peformance
    at org.aspectj.weaver.tools.PointcutParser.parsePointcutExpression(PointcutParser.java:319)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.buildPointcutExpression(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:207)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.checkReadyToMatch(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:193)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJExpressionPointcut.getClassFilter(AspectJExpressionPointcut.java:170)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:194)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.canApply(AopUtils.java:248)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AopUtils.java:280)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findAdvisorsThatCanApply(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:118)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.findEligibleAdvisors(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:88)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.getAdvicesAndAdvisorsForBean(AbstractAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:346)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1583)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
    ... 43 more
```

i read a lot of topics about this problem but i haven't solved yet... maybe i'm searching too far the solution.   I have the followings classes:

i create a interface to be enhance:

```
public interface Performer {
    void peform();
}
```

the impl class：

```
@Component
public class PianoShow implements Performer{
    public void peform() {
        System.out.println("this is a piano show, enjoy it !!!");
    }
}
```

the aop class：

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class AspectJAudience {
    @Pointcut("execution(* org.test.spring.aop.Performer.peform(..))")
    public void performance() {

    }

    @Before("performance()")
    public void takeSeats() {
        System.out.println("The audience is taking their seats.");
    }

    @Before("performance()")
    public void turnOffCellPhones() {
        System.out.println("The audience is turning off their cellphones");
    }

    @AfterReturning("performance()")
    public void applaud() {
        System.out.println("CLAP CLAP CLAP CLAP CLAP");
    }

    @AfterThrowing("peformance()")
    public void demandRefund() {
        System.out.println("Boo! We want our money back!");
    }
}
```

as some topic said, i have update the jar dependency of aop:

```
<properties>
           <spring.version>4.2.6.RELEASE</spring.version>
           <aspect.version>1.8.13</aspect.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>${aspect.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>${aspect.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>cglib</groupId>
    <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and the spring configure file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.test.spring.aop"/>

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
</beans>
```

there are some answer about this kind topic, the solution is just update the version of the aop, i have done as they said, but it doesn't work, any help? thanks!

ps：it works when i use xml configure to execute aop, but it doesn't work when i use annotation way

Comment: you might want to put your last comment in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the spelling mistake in the second AfterThrowing expression. I've highlighted the code needs to be corrected.

```
@AfterThrowing("peformance()")
public void demandRefund() {
    System.out.println("Boo! We want our money back!");
}
```

**@AfterThrowing("peformance()")**

Thanks,
Prabhu